# Select from table1 on condition specific elements from table1 don't exist in table2

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, where-clause

table `words` contains columns: `word_id` `word`

My query prints as:

`SELECT word FROM words WHERE condition1 AND condition2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5000`

table `solved` contains columns: `user_id` `word_id`

I'd like to fetch 5000 random rows, on condition that none of them is found in table `solved` for `user = username`

So far I've tried:

```
SELECT word FROM words w 
WHERE not exists 
(select 1 from solved s where s.word_id = w.word_id 
AND s.user_id = 'username') 
AND condition1 AND condition2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` for thar:

```
SELECT word 
FROM words w 
left join solved s on s.word_id = w.word_id AND s.user_id = 'username'
WHERE w.word_id is null
AND condition1 AND condition2 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5000
```

Comment: You say you want records from first table which has no corresponding records at secod table. Thats becouse `null`